# Fork not in sync with local clone with error, and cannot pull with rebase?

Tags: git, synchronization, git-pull

I have a fork in my github account and I cloned the fork to my local computer. Now I have made some commits, and pushed it to `origin`. Then, I updated the `readme.md` file in the fork directly in GitHub, **not in the local clone**. I made a commit called `Updated readme.md file`.

Now I wanted to sync it with my local computer. So I ran `git pull`.
This gave me the error:

```
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.

Please commit or stash them.
```

After the last commit I have modified 2 files on my local computer. But I no longer want the changes. So, I wanted to remove any changes made to these 2 files and to get in sync with `origin`.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   scripts/filename.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        scripts/anotherfile.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: The untracked file doesn't matter, just delete it. The other one just check out to revert changes: `git checkout scripts/filename.js`.

Comment: if I clearly understood, you need `git reset --hard` it'll rollback your unsaved changes

Comment: @IgorIvancha worked